# sieve in dovecot is not filtering spam message

Tags: spam, dovecot, sieve

In Centos 6.4 i use postfix with LDA Dovecot and webmail squiremail, amavis-new with spamassassin. Spam is marked with subject ***Spam***. I want in my squirelmail to filter spam messages an move in to folder spam. I use sieve script /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve

```
 require "fileinto";
  if exists "X-Spam-Flag" {
          if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "NO" {
          } else {
          fileinto "Spam";
          stop;
          }
  }
  if header :contains "subject" ["***Spam***"] {
    fileinto "Spam";
    stop;
  }
```

but still i have spam in my INBOX folder besides the Spam folder

commandline sievec otuput

```
 #sievec /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
    sievec(root): Error: user root: Initialization failed: Initializing mail storage from environment MAIL failed: Ambiguous mail location setting, don't know what to do with it: /var/spool/mail/root (try prefixing it with mbox: or maildir:)
    sievec(root): Fatal: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

Comment: You saying the sieved messages are still not being filtered, or that it isn't retroactively applying the filter?

Comment: Still I have new messages marked as spam in my inbox

Comment: Any errors in the dovecot log file?

Comment: In my configuation dovecot.log no exists

Comment: in /var/log/maillog isnt any error

Comment: Show what you have in the `mail_location`, `plugin/sieve` and `plugin/sieve_dir` config options.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and in my case the `mail_location` variable wasn't being auto detected correctly.

At **/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf.erb** set:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

This will replace the default which is auto-detect.

You can see a further explanation at the comments at the same file.